# perl script to automate web clicks and pass value to web pasge

Tags: perl, perl-module

I have a webapp hosted in a webpage, I access the page using url,this page has a text box and start button.can i pass a value in the text box and click the start button automatically by using Perl script.

I have used `WWW::Mechanize` module. I am able to get data from webpage but not able to set to anything back on the page.
I am not able to achieve the click functionality also.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds to me like you are trying to fill out a form in a web page. This is possible by fetching the forms of the page via the [`forms` method](http://p3rl.org/WWW%3a%3aMechanize#FORM-METHODS) and then use the resulting [`HTML::Form`](http://p3rl.org/HTML%3a%3aForm) objects.

If you already know, exactly what the form values will be named, you can also use the [`submit_form(with_fields => {…})` method](http://p3rl.org/WWW%3a%3aMechanize#mech-submit_form-...-) to send the form directly without iterating through the forms of the web page. An example of how to do that is found in the [synopsis of the `WWW::Mechanize` documentation](http://p3rl.org/WWW%3a%3aMechanize#SYNOPSIS).

If you need JavaScript, see the [WWW::Mechanize FAQ, section JavaScript](http://p3rl.org/WWW%3a%3aMechanize%3a%3aFAQ#JavaScript): [Which modules work like Mechanize and have JavaScript support?](http://p3rl.org/WWW%3a%3aMechanize%3a%3aFAQ#Which-modules-work-like-Mechanize-and-have-JavaScript-support-)

Comment: [`WWW:Selenium`](https://metacpan.org/module/WWW::Selenium), [`WWW::Mechanize::Firefox`](https://metacpan.org/module/WWW::Mechanize::Firefox)